# Application quit is counting switching scenes?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code, exit

I am making a game in Unity where there are many levels under many scenes. I recently adopted a JSON file saving system that saves the game on application quit.

```
private void OnApplicationQuit()
{
    SaveGame();
}
```

While in retrospect this should work, and while it does, there is an issue. When I load a new Scene or a new Level I believe that the code is interpreting that as OnApplicationQuit. So instead of saving the level you are currently shifting to, it saves the level before you switched. My scenes start out with a start function that loads the data currently saved. A function such as this:

```
void Start() {
    LoadData();
}
```

Because the saved data is from the previous level, this new scene doesn't load the scene I am shifting to but rather the scene before. Is there a way that shifting scenes doesn't interpret it as ApplicationQuiting and only have the SaveGame function called when the application actually closes?

Comment: Is it an iOS project? if yes, then you'll have to set "Exit of suspend" property.

Comment: `OnApplicationQuit` is not guaranteed to be called on all OS properly .. many systems only hibernate and later hard kill the applications. I doubt that switching scene is interpreted as `OnApplicationQuit` ... rather check the loading method etc if there is any saving involved anywhere as well